# Python Tkinter - When I try to use an Entry form on a new window they do not work

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

I have 2 different pieces of code which are the same apart from one is not the first window. For some reason this is somehow stopping the entry fields to work.

Here's my Code:

Working:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def function():
    var.set(text.get()+text2.get())
    print(var.get())

main=Tk()

text=DoubleVar()
text2=DoubleVar()
var=StringVar()

ttk.Entry(main, textvariable=text).grid(column=0, row=0)
ttk.Entry(main, textvariable=text2).grid(column=1, row=0)
ttk.Label(main, textvariable=var).grid(column=2, row=0)
ttk.Button(main, text="Button", command=function).grid(column=0, row=1, columnspan=2)
```

Not Working:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def newwindow():

    def function():
        var.set(text.get()+text2.get())
        print(var.get())

    main=Tk()

    text=DoubleVar()
    text2=DoubleVar()
    var=StringVar()

    ttk.Entry(main, textvariable=text).grid(column=0, row=0)
    ttk.Entry(main, textvariable=text2).grid(column=1, row=0)
    ttk.Label(main, textvariable=var).grid(column=2, row=0)
    ttk.Button(main, text="Button", command=function).grid(column=0, row=1, columnspan=2)

root=Tk()
ttk.Button(text="Button", command=newwindow).grid(column=0, row=0)
```

Comment: Is this your whole code? When I run either one, the program just ends right away. Shouldn't there be a `mainloop` somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to make additional top level windows beyond the first root window, you should make them `Toplevel` objects instead of `Tk`.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def newwindow():

    def function():
        var.set(text.get()+text2.get())
        print(var.get())

    main=Toplevel(root)

    text=DoubleVar()
    text2=DoubleVar()
    var=StringVar()

    ttk.Entry(main, textvariable=text).grid(column=0, row=0)
    ttk.Entry(main, textvariable=text2).grid(column=1, row=0)
    ttk.Label(main, textvariable=var).grid(column=2, row=0)
    ttk.Button(main, text="Button", command=function).grid(column=0, row=1, columnspan=2)

root=Tk()
ttk.Button(text="Button", command=newwindow).grid(column=0, row=0)
root.mainloop()
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I can get back to my main program